# install java on ubuntu 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04, installation, java

I am trying to install java on ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

When I run this I am geting :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-add-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 84, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (6, "Couldn't resolve host 'launchpad.net'")
```

Answer (score 0):

The script tells you that host launchpad.net, on which the PPA is located, is unreachable. Check if you can open it with your browser, fix your network errors and try again.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu, i install ubuntu12.04.2 on VM workstation yesterday. I was able to connect to internet that time.But today am not able to connect. My resolv.conf file is :
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN.

Comment: Please pay a little attention and introduce with markup used here. Paste files through [this site](http://paste.ubuntu.com). And I'm sure that your network settings can be retrieved using `ifconfig` or `netcfg`.